# Excel Chart - Crosshair cursor lines with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Submitting for expert review.

I am trying to create a Chart - Crosshair cursor in excel chart sheet. Chart - Crosshair cursor lines are two lines (one horizontal and other vertical) moving along with the cursor/pointer/mousemove on the chart. Most of the stock market online charts have such interactive tool. I have referred to many webpages such as [Calculating datapoint position with chart mouseover event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426358/calculating-datapoint-position-with-chart-mouseover-event)

Everyone concerned faced the same problem as I did - Calulation of exact cursor position coordinates as the chart is measured in points and cursor position (windows item) is measured in pixels. Somehow, I could calculate it with formula. (Very Close)

I understood cursor position coordinates are determined by following factors.

1. Windows Zoom set by "Make everything bigger" option in control panel/ settings. In Excel this can be determined using (ActiveWindow.Width)
2. Page Size of the Chartsheet (ActiveChart.PageSetup.PaperSize)
3. Page Orientation of the Chartsheet(ActiveChart.PageSetup.Orientation )
4. Zoom percent of the chartsheet (ActiveWindow.Zoom)
5. Chart area size (ChartArea.Width and ChartArea.Height)

for reference [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0f-WGwd0_s). Please note that page margins are set to zero

[image]

Paste this code in excel VBE Chart(Sheet) object.

```
Option Explicit

Private xPoint As Variant, yPoint As Variant, XMax As Variant, YMax As Variant, DispScale As Variant
Private shp As Shape, ChartPaperSize, PgWidPXL, PgHgtPXL, ChtAreaWid, ChtAreaHgt, ActWinZoom
Private shpHL As Variant, shpVL As Variant

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Chart_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal A As Long, ByVal B As Long)
'Dim xPoint As Variant, yPoint As Variant, XMax As Variant, YMax As Variant, DispScale As Variant
'Dim shp As Shape, ChartPaperSize, PgWidPXL, PgHgtPXL, ChtAreaWid, ChtAreaHgt, ActWinZoom
'This macro is suitable for following 4 paper sizes only
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ChartPaperSize = ActiveChart.PageSetup.PaperSize
Select Case ChartPaperSize
' I couldnt find better way to convert paper size number to inches and therafter to pixels
' I dont know why multiplying by 0.9745 or 0.9725 keeps the x, y coordinates more close to the diplayed cursor position
    Case 5 '"xlPaperLegal"
       If ActiveChart.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape Then
       PgWidPXL = 14 * 220 * 0.9745 '220 PPI
       PgHgtPXL = 8.5 * 220 * 0.9725
       Else
       PgWidPXL = 8.5 * 220 * 0.9745
       PgHgtPXL = 14 * 220 * 0.9725
       End If
    Case 1 '"xlPaperLetter"
       If ActiveChart.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape Then
       PgWidPXL = 11 * 220 * 0.9745
       PgHgtPXL = 8.5 * 220 * 0.9725
       Else
       PgWidPXL = 8.5 * 220 * 0.9745
       PgHgtPXL = 11 * 220 * 0.9725
       End If
    Case 9 '"xlPaperA4"
       If ActiveChart.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape Then
       PgWidPXL = 11.69 * 220 * 0.9745
       PgHgtPXL = 8.27 * 220 * 0.9725
       Else
       PgWidPXL = 8.27 * 220 * 0.9745
       PgHgtPXL = 11.69 * 220 * 0.9725
       End If
    Case 8 ' "xlPaperA3"
       If ActiveChart.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape Then
       PgWidPXL = 16.54 * 220 * 0.9745
       PgHgtPXL = 11.69 * 220 * 0.9725
       Else
       PgWidPXL = 11.69 * 220 * 0.9745
       PgHgtPXL = 16.54 * 220 * 0.9725
       End If
    'Case Else
End Select

'Windows display recommended scale of 125% in my computer settings
XMax = PgWidPXL * (100 / 125) ' for A4 2503 for legal 2999 '2395 'Max mousepointer width on 100% chart sheet zoom
YMax = PgHgtPXL * (100 / 125) ' for A4 1764 for legal 1814 '1450 'Max mousepointer height on 100% chart sheet zoom

ChtAreaWid = ChartArea.Width
ChtAreaHgt = ChartArea.Height

DispScale = Round(1161 / ActiveWindow.Width, 2)
' 1161 is ActiveWindow.Width at Windows display recommended scale of 125% on my computer

ActWinZoom = ActiveWindow.Zoom
xPoint = (A * (ChtAreaWid * DispScale) / XMax) / (ActWinZoom / 100)
yPoint = (B * (ChtAreaHgt * DispScale) / YMax) / (ActWinZoom / 100)
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Delete lines
For Each shp In ActiveChart.Shapes
If shp.Type = msoLine Then
shp.Delete
End If
Next

'Add new lines
With ActiveChart.Shapes.AddLine(1, yPoint, ChartArea.Width, yPoint).Line  'horizontal line
.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(150, 150, 150)
.Weight = 5
End With
With ActiveChart.Shapes.AddLine(xPoint, 1, xPoint, ChartArea.Height).Line  'vertical line
.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(150, 150, 150)
.Weight = 5
End With
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Above deletion and addition of new lines could be avoided if two lines are already present
'Say, we manually insert line shapes named "Straight Connector 1" and "Straight Connector 2" then

'With ActiveChart.Shapes("Straight Connector 1") 'horizontal line
'.Left = 1
'.Top = yPoint
'.Width = ChartArea.Width
'.Height = 1
'End With
'With ActiveChart.Shapes("Straight Connector 2") 'vertical line
'.Left = xPoint
'.Top = 1
'.Width = 1
'.Height = ChartArea.Height
'End With
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

End Sub
```

Code works fine. I was wondering if we can avoid deletion and addition of lines with every mouse move. I tried adding lines on chart activate event and then allign those lines using module level variables. But the too procedures cannot work together as by the time chart activate is triggered mouse move already takes place. Any suggestions?

Comment: "Refer YouTube video" Links can rot. Please tell us the purpose of the code in the question itself, so the question is still valid without the link.

Comment: @Mast Added first paragraph. Please see. Thanks for guidance.

Comment: **Margins** in the above chart are set to **zero**  .. Also, noticed [this OLD page](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=374498&seqNum=2) today :)

Comment: One can Use **MouseDown event** instead of MouseMove event to avoid continuous deletion and addition of lines with every mouse move.

Answer (score 2):

After visiting this link, thought of adding extra two xlXYScatterLines series.

https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/interactive-excel-charts-crosshair.3523/post-17715

Whenever a value series is clicked, the series points at the cursor are captured in variables and both the xlXYScatterLines series are updated.

```
Option Explicit

'https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/interactive-excel-charts-crosshair.3523/post-17715
'https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/274401/218583

Private Sub Chart_Mousedown(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, _
                            ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
Data_Points x, y
End Sub

Private Sub Data_Points(ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
Dim ElementID As Long, SrNum As Long, SrName As String, SrPointNum As Long
Dim Newtitle As String, xVals, yVals, SrAx, CHVYVal
Dim CHH As Series, CHV As Series

Me.GetChartElement x, y, ElementID, SrNum, SrPointNum

If ElementID = xlSeries Then

    If SrPointNum <> -1 Then
      With Me.SeriesCollection(SrNum)
        SrName = .Name
        yVals = .Values
        xVals = .XValues
        SrAx = .AxisGroup
        If SrName <> "CHH" And SrName <> "CHV" Then
        Newtitle = .Name & ": " & yVals(SrPointNum) & " @" & _
                            CDate(xVals(SrPointNum))
        Else
        Newtitle = Me.ChartTitle.Text
        End If
      End With
      
    End If

    'adding chart series CHH (CrossHair Horizontal) and CHV (Vertical)
    On Error Resume Next
      If Me.SeriesCollection("CHH") Is Nothing Then
          Set CHH = Me.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
          CHH.Name = "CHH"
      Else
          Set CHH = Me.SeriesCollection("CHH")
      End If
      
      If Me.SeriesCollection("CHV") Is Nothing Then
          Set CHV = Me.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
          CHV.Name = "CHV"
      Else
          Set CHV = Me.SeriesCollection("CHV")
      End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'scaling CHH and CHV series and adding data labels to CHH
    With CHH
      .XValues = Array(LBound(xVals), UBound(xVals))
      .Values = Array(yVals(SrPointNum), yVals(SrPointNum))
      .AxisGroup = SrAx
      .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
      If .HasDataLabels = False Then
          .ApplyDataLabels
          With .DataLabels
            .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
            .Position = xlLabelPositionCenter
              With .Format.Fill
                  .Visible = msoTrue
                  .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
              End With
              With .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
                  .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
                  .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
                  .Bold = msoTrue
              End With
          End With
      End If
    End With
    
    CHVYVal = Array(Me.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MinimumScale, _
                    Me.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MaximumScale)
    
    With CHV
      .XValues = Array(SrPointNum, SrPointNum)
      .Values = CHVYVal
      .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
      .AxisGroup = xlPrimary
    End With
    
    'Adding/ updating chart title with series value
    On Error Resume Next
      If Me.HasTitle = False Then
          Me.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
      End If
      Me.ChartTitle.Text = Newtitle
    On Error GoTo 0
End If

End Sub
```

[youtube video link](https://youtu.be/G-gRxTpFNRo)